# When does 'fraud detection' happen and how do I report it when it involves several posts

Tags: support, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do I do if I suspect someone has downvoted a lot of my posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93142/what-do-i-do-if-i-suspect-someone-has-downvoted-a-lot-of-my-posts)

I think I've been the victim of voter fraud. Should I wait a day (longer?) and see if it's resolved? If and when I do decide to 'report' it, how do I do that? Flag each of my answers?

Comment: What do you mean by voter fraud? Is someone using your votes?

Comment: @jzd, vote(r) fraud generally refers to the situation of being upvoted or downvoted repeatedly by a single user in a short period of time.

Comment: @Popular, yes, that's what I am referring to. I was downvoted 14 times in the span of 3 minutes.

Comment: I don't have a strict answer, so I'm posting this as a comment - I think the script runs at certain points in time so you need to wait for it. In the scenario that it doesn't trigger, then you should only need to flag one of your posts to request investigation. Moderators can see fraud-like voting patterns without needing to know which specific questions are involved, so you only need to point them to the existence of the issue.