# Serial upvoting victim. What to do?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to act when you're being serial upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124842/how-to-act-when-youre-being-serial-upvoted)

Over the last few days in my Stack Overflow account, I received many upvotes which appear to be from the same user since the system reverses everything back.

I know my reputation will be the same as if nothing happened but it is starting to annoy me. My reputation history is messed up by these upvotings.

What can I do?

Comment: The points are corrected and the user will be most likely dealt with if he/she really forms a problem (I'd assume). So I'd say, enjoy that someone out there really really likes you. ;)

Comment: The offending user has been dealt with.

Comment: ...has been dealt with... (* evil laugh *)