# Consider "serial upvoting reversed" count as "removed posts"

Tags: feature-request, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please hide “serial upvoting reversed” entries in the public reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139080/please-hide-serial-upvoting-reversed-entries-in-the-public-reputation-history)

I was a victim of *anonymous* serial upvoting long back. My answers got serially upvoted, reversal algorithm got triggered and those votes were reversed the next day. Everything went fine. The reversed votes appears like **-xx** in my reputation page in a horrible red color which I hate to see. Many think that I've done some voting fraud and paid the price. They talk about it in public and I have to give explanation to prove my innocence. This is quite embarrassing!

Again I got some *anonymous* serial upvotes today. They'll be reversed tomorrow as usual. And that haunting red figure will appear soon in my reputation page. I've had enough of this! Please, not again! I wish not to see it again. Please make that invisible to others or at least add that *serial upvoting reversed* count to *removed posts* so that it won't show up unless you checked the *show removed posts* checkbox.

Comment: Ahh.. Missed the basic part.. _search before you ask_! Sorry.. voting to close..

Comment: But according to shog,the sock puppet will be deleted ..so the description appears like _user removed_. What if the upvoter is a genuine user and not a sock puppet? He won't be deleted and the description remains same.. _serial upvoting reversed_ Shouldn't there be an end for it?

Comment: Can we put the rep undo on the same day as the upvoting? I found my -90 a fortnight ago _really_ demotivating. I'd spent a lot of time on SO and felt as if the community would think I was a cheat. Looking at my rep graph now, that's when my usage and answering dropped off. If it had been counted on the same day as the upvotes, I wouldn't keep seeing the red -90 and the now permanent -45 for that day. It was a week before I started regaining my confidence, and I'm not back to normal yet. I keep seeing questions I could answer and thinking "can I be bothered?". Before I __always__ bothered. :(

Comment: @AndrewC Crap happens mate! And it happened twice to me. :( Something should be done about it